# exception while calling wcf function with params from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, silverlight

I have a big project which is built of Silverlight calling WCF functions on the server. 
Now I want to call the same functions from Javascript using Ajax.

I am able to call a WCF function which takes no parameters, but I get an exception (error 500) when calling a function with parameters.

It all works for me on a clean solution but There is something wrong in my big project which cause it, and I cannot find it.

any help will be appreciated.

following is my SVC file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace MyProj.Web
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service2
    {
        // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
        // To create an operation that returns XML,
        //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
        //     and include the following line in the operation body:
        //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";

        [OperationContract]
        public string Test1() // This function I can call
        {

            return "1";
        }

        [OperationContract]
        public string Test1WithParam(string catID) //on this function I get the exception
        {
            return catID;
        }
   }
}
```

following is my web.config which I believe the problem lies there somewhere:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MyComp\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager enabled="true"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <!--        <authentication mode="Windows"/> -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <!-- The name, protection, and path attributes must match 
           exactly in each Web.config file. -->
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" path="/" domain="MyDomain.com" timeout="600"/>
        </authentication>
        <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
        <machineKey validationKey="MyValidationkey" decryptionKey="MydecryptionKey" validation="SHA1"/>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="administrators"/>
            <allow roles="Others"/>
        </authorization>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    </system.web>
    <!-- Added for server side authentication data to be available in the WCF service -->
    <!-- STX -->
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="false"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!-- ETX -->

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyProj.Web.Service2">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyProj.Web.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior"
                    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyProj.Web.Service2" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyProj.Web.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>

            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>




</configuration>
```

So I logged the error message and got:
got the error: The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).

From this and based on what I read I believe something is wrong in the way I call the service (although as mentioned before is dows work on a clean solution).

So here is my JQuery call:

```
data = '{"catID":"' + '1' + '"}';
Url = "http://MyProjURL/MyProj.Web/Service2.svc/Test1WithParam";
ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
DataType = "json";
Type = "POST";
ProcessData = true;

$.ajax({

    type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb

    url: Url, // Location of the service

    data: Data, //Data sent to server

    contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server

    dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server

    processdata: ProcessData, //True or False

    crossDomain: true,

    success: function (msg) {

        //On Successfull service call

        testSucceeded(msg);

    },

    error: testFailed  // When Service call fails

});
```

Comment: Hi, I can't spot your error right away... Have you checked out this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627082/How-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-JavaScript-Proxy

Comment: The error is: The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true). I know this article. as I mentioned I can make it work in a clean new project. The problem is in my big project and I cann't find the problem.

Comment: OK I see. Then your question is kind of hard to answer. Why not diff the working code (.js and .config) against the not working code!? Do you have a valid auth cookie when you make the call?